# For an operator $T$ compute $ T(v_0)(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the operator $$T: C([-1,1]) \to C([-1,1])$$ defined by 
$$(Tv)(x)=\int^x _{-x} (1+t^3) v(t)dt$$

If $v_0(x)=cos(x)$ how do I find $(Tv_0)(x)$?

How do I show that $T$ is a bounded linear operator?
Do I just apply $T(x+y)=T(x)+t(y)$ and $T(\alpha x)=\alpha T(x)$?

Whereby I substitute x and y for the x in the original expression?

Comment: You just have to plug in $v = \cos$ into the expression and evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Tv_0(x)=\int_{-x}^x (1+t^3)cos t =\int_{-x}^x (cos t+t^3cos t)=\int_{-x}^x cos tdt +0=sin x-sin(-x)=2sinx$$

Comment: thanks for this, out of interest how can we show that $T$ is invertible?